# Blocking a redirect link in an iframe on a chat site

Tags: http

There is a shortened link being spread which contains an @ symbol. j.mp/s@mething, and it's used for phishing purposes.
When trying to block it, for some reason it doesn't like the @ character

I want to know the bit.ly protocol and what code I can use to block this.
http and https don't work for it.

Comment: Question not clear. What you actually want to block this specific website or all URL shortened links?

Comment: I have removed the specific link, as that is unnecessary here. I have also taken out the para you wrote on the two links - of course they are two different things, one uses "@" and one uses "at" - they have nothing to do with blocking a redirect link.

Answer (score 1):

See if using X-Frame-Options header helps, as you want to block it within an iframe. For more information, please refer below link:

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet

You may also want to look at below link to understand how a URL Shortener works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572734/how-does-a-url-shortener-work